# SQL eliminate row when null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have data from Table1:

```
AgeCount    Age      GenderCount      Gender     RaceCount    Race
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12          1-10     null             null       null         null 
10          11-20    null             null       null         null
null        null     3                M          null         null  
null        null     5                F          null         null
null        null     null             null       20           American Indian
null        null     null             null       10           Africa
```

I like a query to remove the `NULL`'s so I will get:

```
AgeCount    Age      GenderCount      Gender     RaceCount   Race
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12          1-10     3                M          20          American Indian 
10          11-20    5                F          10          Africa
```

The non-null values can be joined in any order.

I tried:

```
select *
from table1
where age is not null
or agecount is not null
or gendercount is not null
or gender is not null
or racecount is not null 
or race is not null
```

But its not giving the desired results.

Comment: This is not clear.. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. It seems likely an obvious duplicate. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, the following query produces the desired results:

- It joins 3 sub-queries, 1 for each of the non-null components (Age, Race, Gender)
- It uses a `row_number()` to give an arbitrary join condition
- It uses a `full outer join` to handle the case when there might be more on one type of value than another e.g. if you added another row of of age count

```
    declare @Test table (AgeCount int, Age varchar(16), GenderCount int, Gender varchar(1), RaceCount int, Race varchar(64));

    insert into @Test (AgeCount, Age, GenderCount, Gender, RaceCount, Race)
    values (12, '1-10', null, null, null, null)
    , (10, '11-20', null, null, null, null)
    , (null, null, 3, 'M', null, null)  
    , (null, null, 5, 'F', null, null)
    , (null, null, null, null, 20, 'American Indian')
    , (null, null, null, null, 10, 'Africa');

    select AgeCount, Age, GenderCount, Gender, RaceCount, Race
    from (
      select AgeCount, Age
        , row_number() over (order by AgeCount) row#
      from @Test
      where AgeCount is not null
    ) X
    full outer join
    (
      select GenderCount, Gender
        , row_number() over (order by GenderCount) row#
      from @Test
      where GenderCount is not null
    ) Y on Y.row# = X.row#
    full outer join (
      select RaceCount, Race
        , row_number() over (order by RaceCount) row#
      from @Test
      where RaceCount is not null
    ) Z on Z.row# = X.row#;
```

Gives the following:

```
AgeCount    Age     GenderCount Gender  RaceCount   Race
-------------------------------------------------------------------
10          11-20   3           M       10          Africa
12          1-10    5           F       20          American Indian
```