# SQL remove NULL and Regroup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data on table1

```
ClassA  CountA     ClassB    CountB     ClassC   CountC     Catergory
Test1     2        Test2       1          null     null      Group1
null      null     Test3       2          null     null      Group2
null      null      null       null       Test3     3        Group3
```

How can I redo that can get rid of the NULL and bygroup (group1 = test1, group2 = test2, group3 = test3)

```
ClassA  CountA    Catgroup1   ClassB    CountB  CatGroup2    ClassC   CountC    Catgroup3
Test1     2        Group1      Test2      1       Group2     Test3      2        Group3
                               Test3      3                                      Group3
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why does `ClassC` have 2 rows and not `ClassB`?

Comment: I really dont know how to do this. I'm just new beginner

Comment: Just for data records. nothing specific

Comment: So what happened to `Test3` for `ClassB`? Explain the logic. Why are things moving?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected it

Comment: SO, why has `'Test2'` moved to `'GroupB'`?

Comment: Just random data records. Test1 , test 2, test3 can be any column class

Comment: If we don't understand *why* your data is changing from the sample to the expected, how can we give you an answer? There is only one answer to that question: we can't

Comment: normal can use query check null like this `ISNULL(ClassA, '') As  ClassA`

Comment: Seems pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880077/sql-eliminate-row-when-null) - I'd love to know the business case for such a query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real pain.  Basically, you have to do each column independently and then bring them back together.

Note that you cannot keep the original ordering, unless you have a column specifying the ordering.  The idea is to generate a sequence number for each valid value in each column and bring them back together using `full join`:

```
select classA.classA, countA.countA, classB.classB, . . . 
from (select classA, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      where classA is not null
     ) classA full join
     (select countA, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      where countA is not null
     ) countA
     on classA.seqnum = countA.seqnum full join
     (select classB, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
      where classB is not null
     ) classB
     on classB.seqnum = coalesce(classA.seqnum, countA.seqnum) full join
     . . .
order by seqnum;
```

Comment: I don't see group by Category column